# Refactoring: AbstractList adapter vs. for-each conversion in Java 7?

Tags: java, coding-style, refactoring

When should using an adapter pattern using an `AbstractList` be favoured over a building a result list from another list via for-each?

Given the following Java beans (skipping getters/setters for readability):

```
class ObjectError {
  private String code;
}

class FieldError extends ObjectError {
  private String field;
}

class ErrorMessage {
  private String path;
  private String messageKey;
}
```

and the following methods of the `Validator` class:

```
public AllErrors validate(List<ObjectError> errors) {
   AllErrors result= new AllErrors();
   result.setErrors(convertErrors(errors));
   return result;
}

List<ErrorMessage> convertErrors(List<ObjectError> errors) {
  List<ErrorMessage> result = new ArrayList<>(errors.size());
  for (ObjectError error : errors) {
    ErrorMessage message = new ErrorMessage();

    if (error instanceof FieldError) {
       message.setMessageKey(((FieldError) error)).getPath();
    }
    message.setPath(error.getCode());
    result.add(message);
  }
  return result;
}
```

I would like to refactor `convertErrors`.

First we can extract the contents of the for loop to a `createErrorMessage` method, so `convertErrors` does the list iteration and `createErrorMessage` knows how to create a single `ErrorMessage` from a `ObjectError` instance:

```
List<ErrorMessage> convertErrors(List<ObjectError> errors) {
  List<ErrorMessage> result = new ArrayList<>(errors.size());
  for (ObjectError error : errors) {
    result.add(createErrorMessage(error));
  }
  return result;
}

ErrorMessage createErrorMessage(ObjectError error) {
  ErrorMessage message = new ErrorMessage();

  if (error instanceof FieldError) {
    message.setMessageKey(((FieldError) error)).getPath();
  }
  message.setPath(error.getCode());
  return message;
}
```

Now there are two options:

### Keeping things the way they are

The current code can be read from top to bottom, but the components of the `Validator` class are not quite reusable.

### Using an `AbstractList` adapter

The `convertErrors` method can be replaced with a List adapter:

```
private static class ObjectErrorAdapter extends AbstractList<ErrorMessage> {

  private List<ObjectError> objectErrors;

  private ObjectErrorAdapter(List<ObjectError> objectErrors) {
    this.objectErrors = objectErrors;
  }

  @Override public ErrorMessage get(int idx) {
    return createErrorMessage(objectErrors.get(idx));
  }

  @Override public int size() {
    return objectErrors.size();
  }

  ErrorMessage createErrorMessage(ObjectError error) {
    ErrorMessage message = new ErrorMessage();

    if (error instanceof FieldError) {
      message.setMessageKey(((FieldError) error)).getPath();
    }
    message.setPath(error.getCode());
    return message;
  }

  // Also hashCode() and equals() might be required for this class   
}

public AllErrors validate(List<ObjectError> errors) {
   AllErrors result= new AllErrors();
   result.setErrors(new ObjectErrorAdapter(errors));
   return result;
}
```

This variant adds a lot of code and some indirections, but seemingly increases modularity, reusability and thus testability(?).

Which variant is preferable and why?

Comment: Unless I am missing some bigger picture I see any benefit from using that ObjectErrorAdapter. Also I had encountered issues with non-standard Lists like one returned from `Arrays.asList()` so I would stay away from implementing custom list, even if it is some lazy-loading wrapper.

Comment: I see no increase in modularity, reusability, or testability.  If anything, you will get more of those by using an existing implementation of List, since you can choose to change the implementation much more easily.

Answer (score 0):

The code using `AbstractList` is more complex and less understandable.
Since you do not have any specific reason to refactor this (premature optimisation?), I would leave it as is.